# How to mount adls Gen2 account in databrikcs using access keys

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

i want to mount adls gen 2 storage accounts in azure databricks .but I am using an azure account where i don't have access to create service principal.So i am trying to mount the containers using access keys, But i keep on getting errors.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.azadfdatalakegen2.dfs.core.windows.net",dbutils.secrets.get(scope="azdatabricks-adlsgen2SA", key="Azdatrbricks-adlsgen2-accesskeys"))
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = "abfss://raw@azadfdatalakegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/",
      mount_point = "/mnt/raw_adlsmnt")
```

i keep on getting the below error message

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ExecutionError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <command-555436758533424> in <module>
>       1 spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.azadfdatalakegen2.dfs.core.windows.net",dbutils.secrets.get(scope="azdatabricks-adlsgen2SA",
> key="Azdatrbricks-adlsgen2-accesskeys"))
> ----> 2 dbutils.fs.mount(
>       3   source = "abfss://raw@azadfdatalakegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/",
>       4   mount_point = "/mnt/raw_adlsmnt")
> 
> /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/dbutils.py in
> f_with_exception_handling(*args, **kwargs)
>     387                     exc.__context__ = None
>     388                     exc.__cause__ = None
> --> 389                     raise exc
>     390 
>     391             return f_with_exception_handling
> 
> ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o548.mount. :
> java.lang.NullPointerException: authEndpoint  at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
>   at
> shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator.getTokenUsingClientCreds(AzureADAuthenticator.java:84)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureOAuth(DBUtilsCore.scala:803)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.verifyAzureFileSystem(DBUtilsCore.scala:814)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.createOrUpdateMount(DBUtilsCore.scala:734)
>   at
> com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore.mount(DBUtilsCore.scala:776)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)    at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)     at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)    at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any way we can mount adls gen 2 container using access keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databricks no longer recommends mounting external data locations to the Databricks Filesystem; see [Mounting cloud object storage on Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/mounts).

> Best way or recommended way is set configurations on Spark to
> accessing ADLS Gen2 and then access storage file with URLs.

**Below screenshot shows accessing ADLS gen2 with Account key.**
[image]
Check below link for same.
[Access ADLS Gen2 storage using Account Key in Azure Databricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_mbpd0oqOE&list=PLMWaZteqtEaKi4WAePWtCSQCfQpvBT2U1&index=28)

**Below screenshot shows accessing ADLS gen2 with SAS Token**
[image]
Check below link for same.
[Access ADLS Gen2 or Blob Storage using a SAS token in Azure Databricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lkN0lTzl60&list=PLMWaZteqtEaKi4WAePWtCSQCfQpvBT2U1&index=31)

Please note, use SAS token at storage level to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount Storage Account with Azure databrikcs .Follow below syntax:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://pool@vamblob.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/io234",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.vamblob.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "demo_secret", key = "demo123")})
```

**Output:**

[image: Ref1]

**Alternative Approach**

First of all create App regestration in active directory you will get `client.id`,`tenent id` .

[image: Ref1]

`Client Secret` created in AAD

[image: Ref1]

**Please follow below syntax for creating mount storage:**

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "xxxxxxxxx", 
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "xxxxxxxxx", 
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token", 
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<folder_name>", 
mount_point = "/mnt/<folder_name>",
extra_configs = configs)
```

For more information refer this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6931/mount-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-databricks/) by Ron L'Esteve

Comment: Hi Vamsi. Thanks for the reply. In the first approach you have mounted a blob storage. But i want to mount datalake gen 2 storage account. if possible can you try mounting adls gen2 account with SAS or access keys .?